# Sample from one distribution such that it’s PDF matches another distribution

Tags: sampling, density-estimation, divergence

**Problem**: I have a set of samples from a continuous distribution (multivariate), call this set $W$. I have another set of samples from a different distribution $X$. I want to sample from $W$ (with replacement of course), call this $V$, such that the PDF of $V$ is as close as possible to that of $X$ (from a KL divergence perspective).

It is possible that some samples from $W$ exist in $X$ but that isn’t a guarantee.

I don’t know any of the PDFs, so I am estimating them with kernel density estimation.

Of course, I can sample one point at a time, add it to my set, do a KDE, determine it’s divergence from the KDE of $X$, and choose the point that gives the least divergence at each step. But that is basically exhaustive search, I was wondering if there is a niftier method to accomplish this task.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Find the subset of $W$ that minimises the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance between $X$ and that subset.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks! I have two questions though. First, isn’t that an intractable problem? There are an infinite amount of subsets of $W$ since we can sample with replacement. And second, does minimizing the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance also imply minimizing the KL Divergence?

Comment: @Xi'an thank you, I understand now how the amount eCDFs is finite, thinking through it. Although finite, isn’t the amount of possible eCDFs intractably large?

Comment: The number of distinct ECDFs when $W$ is of cardinal $n$ is $2^n-1$